# Set the size of JTextField fixed in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield, layout-manager

for school I am working on a Java GUI program to store some administrative data.

Now I want to display eventdata from my DB (mysql) into a JPanel with use of a JTextField,
my problem is I can't get the size of the JTextField fixed as it always takes up a lot of place (see picture)

Picture: http://postimg.org/image/5pcklo5n1/

Here's my code, anyone some tips? (I am new to java):

```
public void editEvent() {
    JFrame frEventEdit = new JFrame ("Event Edit Menu");
    frEventEdit.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frEventEdit.setVisible(true);   
    frEventEdit.setSize(700, 500);


    //JPanel for displaying data
    JPanel pnData = new JPanel();
    pnData.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnData, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));
    pnData.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,5)));
    pnData.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10,10,10,10));
    pnData.setAutoscrolls(true);

    Statement stmt;
    try {
        stmt = mySql.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT name, date, time, type, address, representative FROM events " ) ;
        while (rs.next() == true){
            System.out.println(rs.getString("name")+"  "+rs.getString("date")+"  "+rs.getString("time")+"  "+rs.getString("type")+"  "+rs.getString("address")+"  "+rs.getString("representative"));
            final JTextField txtEventList = new JTextField(rs.getString("name")+"  "+rs.getString("date")+"  "+rs.getString("time")+"  "+rs.getString("type")+"  "+rs.getString("address")+"  "+rs.getString("representative"));
            pnData.add(txtEventList, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(pnData);
    frEventEdit.add(scroller);
    frEventEdit.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 

}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (factor out the DB by hard coding some data. 2) Provide ASCII art of the GUI as it should appear in smallest size and (if resizable) with extra width/height. 3) The `while (rs.next() == true){` suggests a `JTable` instead of many components.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It happens because you use `BoxLayout`,try to use `FlowLayout` which is default for `JPanel` or another.
2. In next statement `pnData.add(txtEventList, BorderLayout.CENTER);` , `BorderLayout.CENTER` doesn't work, because you doesn't use `BorderLayout` for your panel.
3. For fixing size of `JTextField`, use [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextField.html#JTextField(int)) `JTextField(int cols)`.
4. For your purposes use `JTable` as recommended by @AndrewThompson. [Tutorial for table](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html).
5. call `frEventEdit.setVisible(true);` at the end of construction or like next:

   ```
   SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

       @Override
       public void run() {
           frEventEdit.setVisible(true);
       }
   });
   ```

Comment: Thanks, that helped much! For now I fixed it by using a JTable as AndrewThompson said, took me a while to figure out but I got it now! Thanks!