# How can I set the size of JTextField?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I was trying to set size of JButton or JTextField or JPanel but somehow I didn't manage to do that.
I tried

```
JTextField FirstName = new JTextField("First Name");
FirstName.setSize(new Dimension(40, 20));
```

and

```
JTextField FirstName = new JTextField("Fisrt Name");
FirstName.setSize(40, 20);
```

but none of them worked. How can I achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Use `JTextField#setColumns` to specify the preferred width of the field, you appropriate layout managers and where applicable sizing hints via constraints.  Don't use `setSize`, `setBounds`, `setPreferred/Minimum/MaximumSize`, these will all blow up your face. See [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html) for more details

Comment: I would also recommend you learn Java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20243956/set-the-size-of-jtextfield-fixed-in-a-jpanel) would help you.